# Exporting a Data Set (package development)

Tags: r, roxygen2, package-development

I have a package ([qdap](https://github.com/trinker/qdap)) and an accompanying data only package ([qdapDictionaries](https://github.com/trinker/qdapDictionaries)) that will be used by some of the functions in qdap as seen [here](https://github.com/trinker/qdap/blob/master/R/synonyms.R) in line 41 I use the syn.env from line 454 [here](https://github.com/trinker/qdapDictionaries/blob/master/R/qdapDictionaries-package.R).

I have already asked [a related question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Incorporating-a-dataset-only-package-td4674507.html) on the R-help list but was told off list it was not appropriate for the list as it uses private notation from roxygen2, however, I could actually export the data sets from `qdapDictionaries`.  I [tried simply adding `@export`](https://github.com/trinker/qdapDictionaries/blob/master/R/qdapDictionaries-package.R) to the .R file that describes the data sets but this results in an error when compiling.

```
> set(qdapDictionaries)
Installing qdapDictionaries
"C:/R/R-3.0.1/bin/i386/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\trinker\GitHub\qdapDictionaries" --library="C:/R/R-3.0.1/library"  \
  --with-keep.source --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'qdapDictionaries' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: abbreviations, action.verbs, adverb, amplification.words, BuckleySaltonSWL, contractions, deamplification.words, DICTIONARY, emoticon, env.pol, env.syl, env.syn, interjections, labMT, NAMES, NAMES_LIST, NAMES_SEX, negation.words, negative.words, OnixTxtRetToolkitSWL1, positive.words, preposition, SYNONYM, Top100Words, Top200Words, Top25Words
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: abbreviations, action.verbs, adverb, amplification.words, BuckleySaltonSWL, contractions, deamplification.words, DICTIONARY, emoticon, env.pol, env.syl, env.syn, interjections, labMT, NAMES, NAMES_LIST, NAMES_SEX, negation.words, negative.words, OnixTxtRetToolkitSWL1, positive.words, preposition, SYNONYM, Top100Words, Top200Words, Top25Words
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing 'C:/R/R-3.0.1/library/qdapDictionaries'
* restoring previous 'C:/R/R-3.0.1/library/qdapDictionaries'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Clearly I am not exporting these data sets correctly.  **How can I export the data sets from `qdapDictionaries` so that I can then use `@importFrom` in the parent `qdap` package?**

Here is what one of the documentations for the data sets looks like:

```
#' Fry's  100 Most Commonly Used English Words
#' 
#' A stopword list containing a character vector of stopwords. 
#' 
#' @details Fry's Word List: The first 25 make up about one-third of all printed 
#' material in English. The first 100 make up about one-half of all printed 
#' material in English. The first 300 make up about 65\% of all printed 
#' material in English."
#' 
#' 
#' @docType data 
#' @keywords datasets 
#' @name Top100Words 
#' @usage data(Top100Words) 
#' @format A character vector with 100 elements 
#' @export
#' @references Fry, E. B. (1997). Fry 1000 instant words. Lincolnwood, IL: 
#' Contemporary Books.
NULL
```

Note that I have the `qdapDictionaries` listed in the Depends section of the DESCRIPTION file but with R dev version a CRAN check reveals I need to still import the datasets from `qdapDictionaries` that are used within the parent `qdap` package.

Comment: Is the data in `sysdata.rda` or `data/`? And have you looked at what other data only packages do?

Comment: @hadley the data is in `data/`.  I have looked at `slidifyLibraries` but this is a bit different in that it's not an R dataset but `java-ish` libraries  to access the data).  The only other data only package I know of is `datasets` and that is a bit different in that no other packages are relying on it that I know of plus I can't find a tar.gz of it to look at the documentation setup (I have used `untar` to view the files from CRAN packages in raw format).  If you had an example (particularly a github repo) of this use of a datasets package I'd use it to create an answer for this question.